# chef client does not run as regular intervals

Tags: chef-infra

When I execute the command chef-client -i 30 in my node machine, it waits first thirty seconds and then only it running. I want to make it run first and then only it waits 30 seconds. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you want to elaborate on what you want to achieve. I (hope I) answered your question, but I'm not very sure, why you need this.

Comment: @StephenKing No I just dont want to wait for the initial 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
# chef-client; sleep 30
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way with chef options, the implementation is done like this.

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html)

> -i SECONDS, --interval SECONDS The frequency (in seconds) at which the chef-client runs. When the chef-client is run at intervals, --splay
>   and --interval values are applied before the chef-client run. Default
>   value: 1800.
>
> -s SECONDS, --splay SECONDS A random number between zero and splay that is added to interval. Use splay to help balance the load on the
>   Chef server by ensuring that many chef-client runs are not occuring at
>   the same interval. When the chef-client is run at intervals, --splay
>   and --interval values are applied before the chef-client run.

If you want to manage the interval another way you'll have to do it yourself, within an infinite loop for exemple.

Comment: so can I do like this chef client sleep 30 this will come under an infinite loops

Comment: Even If I find this absolutely unneeded, yes, you can avoid the 30 sec at startup like this. I really can't see a good reason to insert this complexity, but do as you wish, if @StephenKing answer is ok for you, think marking it as accepted.

Comment: K @Tensibai But if there any other solution for this? to avoid the first 30 sec startup?

Comment: A crontab to run periodically, without knowing why you have this requirement we can't give a proper answer

Comment: No At every time I run this command why i wait for initial 30 sec??that is my question??@tensibai

Comment: Because this parameter is meant to be used in a daemon mode never stopping and not for manual launch